# Allauth Social Login with DRF JWT

Tags: django, jwt, django-allauth

I am using DRF, DRF-JWT, Allauth and Res-auth, and djangorestframework-jwt-refresh-token in my Django Application.

I have a custom JWT Register Serializer to collect some additional user info and create and create a refresh-token that is used to refresh expired JWT tokens. We have that working across back-end and iOS Application with no problems for email signup. I am now trying to implement the JWT with the sociallogin element of allauth in particular Facebook as a provider.

I can create a refresh token against a Facebook user by overriding the DefaultSocialAccountAdapter but I'm struggling to return a JSON response with a JWT with said refresh token to mobile client.

This creates refresh token:

```
class CustomSocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def save_user(self, request, sociallogin, form):
    user = super(CustomSocialAccountAdapter, self).save_user(request, sociallogin, form)
    app = 'users'
    user.refresh_tokens.create(app=app)
    return user
```

I can create JWT manually with this:

```
jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER

payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
```

I'm just having difficulty putting it all together, should I be overriding the adapter or using pre_social_login signal.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I went with the following to return the long lived refresh token along with avatar url on the Facebook Login:

```
class CustomJWTSerializer(JWTSerializer):
    """
    OVERIDE JWTSerializer Base Serializer for JWT authentication to 
    add long refresh_token to returned JSON
    """
    refresh_token = serializers.CharField()
    avatar_url = serializers.CharField()



class FacebookLogin(SocialLoginView):

    adapter_class = FacebookOAuth2Adapter

    def process_login(self):
        get_adapter(self.request).login(self.request, self.user)

        user = self.request.user
            app = 'users'
            try:
                refresh_token = user.refresh_tokens.get(app=app).key
            except RefreshToken.DoesNotExist:
                refresh_token = None
            if refresh_token == None:
             app = 'users'
             user.refresh_tokens.create(
                app=app
             )
        preferred_avatar_size_pixels = 256
        facebook_social_account = SocialAccount.objects.get(user=user)
        uid = facebook_social_account.uid
        picture_url = "http://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?width={1}&height={1}".format(
        uid, preferred_avatar_size_pixels)
        profile = Profile(user=user, avatar_url=picture_url)
        profile.save()



    def get_response(self):
        serializer_class = CustomJWTSerializer
        refresh_token = RefreshToken.objects.get(user=self.user)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.user)
        avatar_url = profile.avatar_url

        if getattr(settings, 'REST_USE_JWT', False):
            data = {
                'user': self.user,
                'token': self.token,
                'refresh_token': refresh_token,
                'avatar_url': avatar_url
            }
            serializer = serializer_class(instance=data,
                                      context={'request': self.request})
        else:
            serializer = serializer_class(instance=self.token,
                                      context={'request': self.request})

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I don't know if this was the proper way to do this, but it works for now.